# Formatting of text inside button-bar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the formatting of a text string inside a `button` in a `button-bar` in Ionic. I want to set a max-width of the text inside the button, such that the last word goes down on a separate row but couldn't make it work using css.

```
<div class="button-bar">
     <a class="button" ng-click="data.filter='cat'">Cats cats and more cats</a>
     <a class="button" ng-click="data.filter='dog'">Dogs</a>
     <a class="button" ng-click="data.filter='bird'">Birds</a>
</div>
```

I want the last word "cats" in the first button go down on a separate row. I can't use any html tags or separate the string in any way, since in the real scenario I am getting the string from a translation table. Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLMRym)

Comment: I can't view the word in Codepen.io

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

White-space CSS did the trick.

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button" style="white-space:normal" ng-click="data.filter='cat'">Cats cats and more cats</a>
    <a class="button" ng-click="data.filter='dog'">Dogs</a>
    <a class="button" ng-click="data.filter='bird'">Birds</a>
</div>
```

You can refer to the updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLMRdp)